# Thrift driver OutOfMemory when running multiple Hive queries simultaneously

Tags: out-of-memory, thrift, apache-spark-2.0

we use Spark2 Thrift in order to run Hive queries.

Thrift comes as part of the HDP 2.6 and our spark version is 2.1.0.2.6.0.3-8.

The more queries we run simultaneously, the faster we encounter OOM in the driver. These queries also contain JOINs and UNIONs.

from the jstat is seems there's no memory leak, however no matter how much memory is given to the driver, it seems it's never enough. The more queries that are run simultaneously, the faster Thrift driver starts to perform full GC until it crashes, since the full GC can't clean the old memory (since it's being used).

The OOM never occurs in the executors, only in the driver.

Does anyone work with Thrift over spark and encounters this problem? and if so - how can the Thrift driver be configured not to crash on OOM when running several queries simultaneously?

These are the configurations we use:

**Thrift spark driver:**

- spark.driver.memory=15g

**Thrift spark executors:**

- spark.executor.memory=10g
- num cores = 7

**config params from /usr/hdp/current/spark2-thriftserver/conf/spark-thrift-sparkconf.conf:**

- spark.broadcast.blockSize 32m
- spark.driver.extraLibraryPath /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
- spark.driver.maxResultSize 0
- spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
- spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout 45s
- spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors 2
- spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 15
- spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 0
- spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout 1s
- spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///spark2-history/
- spark.eventLog.enabled true
- spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
- spark.executor.memory 10g
- spark.files.maxPartitionBytes 268435456
- spark.files.openCostInBytes 33554432
- spark.hadoop.cacheConf false
- spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs:///spark2-history/
- spark.history.provider org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
- spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 2000m
- spark.master yarn-client
- spark.memory.offHeap.enabled true
- spark.memory.offHeap.size 104857600
- spark.scheduler.allocation.file /usr/hdp/current/spark2-thriftserver/conf/spark-thrift-fairscheduler.xml
- spark.scheduler.mode FAIR
- spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
- spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold 1073741824
- spark.sql.shuffle.partitions 100
- spark.storage.memoryMapThreshold 8m

Comment: I'd guess "Spark over Thrift" would be the more appropriate term.

Comment: @elad-eldor Did you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scheduler mode to FIFO.

Also, dont forget there are 2 different zones in memory :
- storage
- execution

Storage will use by défaut 60% of driver memory, so if you never cache data, decrease it to give more memory where its needed (they say its done automatically but ...).

Try decreasing spark shuffle partition to 100 then 10 if possible.

Try offheap (never tested but could help).

Comment: why FIFO better than FAIR?     Also - do you mean using 10 shuffle partitions instead of 100?

Comment: FIFO is better for resources (because a single query is running at one time).  I found decreasing Spark partition for small workload can be better, try it, check on webUI the size of partition, the max is 2Go, less partitions mean less shuffle operations (so less resources usage).

Comment: we have multi-user environment with multiple queries that should run simultaneously. do you recommend in such environment to change from FAIR to FIFO? and to decrease the number of shuffle partitions from 100 to 10?